# SwiftUI Adding Text to Path

Tags: swiftui, path

I'm looking to add text inside the arc's, but I'm not finding that I can overlay text. For testing I'm just trying to get the angle text in earthyStatsInTonnes. I've tried using `GeometryReader` but the font just ends up overlapping each other in the center.

[image]

```
struct Shapes: View {

private enum Params {
    static var viewSizeOffset: CGFloat = 100
    static let lineWidth: CGFloat = 20
    static var halfLineWidth: CGFloat {
        lineWidth / 2
    }

    static let animationDuration: CGFloat =
        0.05 // nominal animation to smooth things
    static let circleDegrees: CGFloat = 360
    static let circleRotation: Angle = .init(degrees: -90)
    static let offsetFactor: CGFloat = 0.4
    static let minCircleAngle: CGFloat = 00
    static let maxCircleAngle: CGFloat = 360
    static var minCircleTrim: CGFloat {
        minCircleAngle / circleDegrees
    }

    static var maxCircleTrim: CGFloat {
        maxCircleAngle / circleDegrees
    }

    static let progressColor = Color.red
    static let backgroundColor = Color.blue
    static let arcFrame: CGFloat = 225
}

    @State private var rotation: Double = 0
    @State var earthyStatsInTonnes = [2.6, 3.0, 5.4, 6.75, 0.0]
    @State private var increment = 0
    let arcColor = [Color.red, Color.gray, Color.black, Color.green, Color.purple, Color.blue]


    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                ZStack {
                    Text("Text \(angle)")
                        .position(
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0
                        )
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.red.opacity(0.2))
                        .frame(width: Params.arcFrame + 36, height: Params.arcFrame + 36)
                        ForEach(earthyStatsInTonnes.indices) { stat in
                            VStack {
                                ZStack {
                                    arcView(startAngle: stat == 0 ? 00 : earthyStatsInTonnes[stat],
                                            endAngle: earthyStatsInTonnes[stat],
                                            total: 17.8,
                                            arcColor: arcColor[stat])

                                }
                                .zIndex(-Double(stat))
                            }
                        }
                }
                .frame(width: Params.arcFrame, height: Params.arcFrame)
                .padding(45)
            }
            .position(x: geo.size.width / 2, y: geo.size.height / 2)
        }
    }

    private func arcView(startAngle: Double, endAngle: Double, total: Double, arcColor: Color) -> some View {

        return Arc(startAngle: .degrees(startAngle * total),
                   endAngle: .degrees(startAngle * total + (endAngle * total)),
                   clockwise: true)
        .stroke(arcColor,
                style: .init(lineWidth: 36,
                             lineCap: .round,
                             lineJoin: .miter,
                             miterLimit: 0,
                             dash: [2, 3],
                             dashPhase: 1))
        .frame(width: 226, height: 229)
    }

    func onDrag(value: DragGesture.Value) {
        let circleDegrees = Params.circleDegrees
        // Calculate radians
        let vector = CGVector(dx: value.location.x, dy: value.location.y)
        let radians = atan2(
            vector.dy - Params.halfLineWidth,
            vector.dx - Params.halfLineWidth
        )

        var angle = radians * circleDegrees / 2 / .pi

        // atan2 gives -180 to 180, so set range to 0 to 360
        if angle < 0 {
            angle += circleDegrees
        }

        // constrain angle between desired range
        angle = max(angle, Params.minCircleAngle)
        angle = min(angle, Params.maxCircleAngle)

        withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: Params.animationDuration)) {
            self.angle = Double(angle)
        }
    }
}


struct Arc: Shape {
    var startAngle: Angle
    var endAngle: Angle
    var clockwise: Bool

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let rotationAdjustment = Angle.degrees(90)
        let modifiedStart = startAngle - rotationAdjustment
        let modifiedEnd = endAngle - rotationAdjustment

        var path = Path()
        path.addArc(center: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY),
                    radius: rect.width / 2,
                    startAngle: modifiedStart,
                    endAngle: modifiedEnd,
                    clockwise: !clockwise)

        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Not clear where exactly you want to locate Text, can you make a sketch somehow?